# 18.04 - Failing to shutdown/power off after upgrade Kernel 4.15.0.108.96 to 4.15.0.111.99 or 5.3.0.61.114 to 5.3.0-62.56

Tags: bug-reporting

I use an Acer Notebook with a fresh installation of Ubunto 18.04.
Till the last upgrade everything works as expected.
The last upgrade brings two new kernel versions (as mentioned above).
Now the system stucks at the very end of the power down sequence.
Because I use Systemback, I timeshift to the previrious system and then install package by package to see what will bring in the problem.
If I install any of the mentioned kernel updates the probem will show up.

I found a lot of similar problems by searching the web, but none is related to this combination.
Please indicated what information I should provide for fixing this.

Something I found today:

Even when I block the above mentioned kernels (via APT pinning) the problem ocours after "apt upgrade".
It seams, that I must block linux-firmware too.
(Installed was 1.173.18 upgrade to 1.173.19 will result in the problem)

I am not shure if I do it right (APT pinning).
I currently create a file /etc/apt/prefereces.d/kernel. After doing so "apt list --upgradeable" will not list the packages in question.

I add an entry for every of the following packages to block the newest version (Pin-Priority: -1):

linux-generic, linux-image-generic, linux-image-4.15.0-111-generic, linux-generic-hwe-18.04, linux-headers-generic, linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04, linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04, linux-modules-nvidia-440-generic, linux-modules-nvidia-440-generic-hwe-18.04, linux-firmware

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact model # of your computer.

Comment: > sudo dmidecode -s bios-version  
V1.15

> sudo lshw  
...
Beschreibung: Notebook
Produkt:  Aspire E5-771G (Aspire E5-771G_0884_1_15)
Hersteller: Acer
Version: V3.72
....

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

Aspire E5-771G-0884

You have BIOS v1.15.

There's a newer BIOS available which may solve your problem. It's v1.23, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/SI/content/support-product/5457?b=1).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: Yes it seams to be the right web page. I now have to check what they ofer there (6 BIOs updates listed). Then make a complete system backup und try if the bios update solves the problem... So I think I can report tomorrow earliest. Thanks for Your help so far.

Comment: How can I update the bios if they only offer Windos exe for Bios upgrade :-((

Comment: @NeißGünter You can either try building a bootable FreeDOS USB flash drive, or you'll have to, at least temporarily, install Windows somewhere. PS: at the web site, there's only one BIOS 1.23... the rest are all older.

Comment: I now had created a DvD with "Hiren's BootCD PE v1.0.1", booted this and run the "ZYW_123.exe" BIOS Updater. This Programm starts, but after it indicates the current and new Bios versions the Programm terminates (can't see any error msg). Ater a rebbot I got an "image error" the system then rebbots (seams to be a fail safe bios) and anything is as before :-(( So it seams that I need a real Windows :-(((

Comment: @NeißGünter Or try FreeDOS.

Comment: FreeDos will not work (unable too create page tables), But booting the Hirens CD with UEFI enabled will do the trick. I had now BIOS version 1.23 but the problem still persistist. So it's not related to BIOS.

Comment: @NeißGünter Good job on the BIOS update. I don't know about other fixes for the problem, other than a Ubuntu reinstall. Sorry.

Comment: I had filled a bug report in lauchnpad, may I find a solution there. Thanks for tryng to help